# IndentationError: unexpected unindent for no reason

Tags: python, indentation

I feel like I'm dealing with something very basic right here but couldn't find it.

```py
def guess(guess_l: str) -> list:
    if player:
        while True:
            print("Please enter the results of my guess below in a list.")
            print("For example, if your answer is 'alias', and I guessed 'i', reply [3].")
            print("If I guessed 'a', reply [1,4].")
            print("If I guessed 's', reply [0].")
            letter_list=input("Enter your reply:")
            try:
                if letter_list == [0]:
                    letter_list = []
                print('here')
                letter_list=list(letter_list)
                for number in letter_list:
                    number+=1
            #except TypeError:
                #print("Incorrect syntax")
    else:
        letter_list = []
        letter_no = 0
        for ltr in secret_word:
            if ltr == guess_l:
                letter_list.append(letter_no)
            letter_no += 1
    return letter_list
```

And the error was:

```
  File "/Users/scythia/Desktop/hangman/main.py", line 32
    else:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: it's actually because you have a `try` without an `except`. if you un-comment the `except` clause, it interprets just fine.

Comment: (and yea, the error isn't very helpful to get there... :P)

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `except` block after `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `try` without an `except`. If you don't want to do anything in except, use

`except TypeError: pass`

```
def guess(guess_l: str) -> list:
    if player:
        while True:
            print("Please enter the results of my guess below in a list.")
            print("For example, if your answer is 'alias', and I guessed 'i', reply [3].")
            print("If I guessed 'a', reply [1,4].")
            print("If I guessed 's', reply [0].")
            letter_list=input("Enter your reply:")
            try:
                if letter_list == [0]:
                    letter_list = []
                print('here')
                letter_list=list(letter_list)
                for number in letter_list:
                    number+=1
            except TypeError: pass
                #print("Incorrect syntax")
    else:
        letter_list = []
        letter_no = 0
        for ltr in secret_word:
            if ltr == guess_l:
                letter_list.append(letter_no)
            letter_no += 1
    return letter_list
```